# Что же все-таки означает объект, ссылка на объект?

Tags: java

Всем привет. Есть такая запись.

```
Robot enemy = new Robot("Рботот");
```

Можете расписать по пунктам и подробно что такое

1. Robot
2. Enemy
3. new Robot

Хочу раз и навсегда понять, что это все значит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot - тип переменной enemy. В простом случае именно этот тип можно присваивать переменной. 
enemy - переменная. Она сейчас станет объектом класса Robot. ПОка же она просто этого типа, то есть под нее выделено необходимое место в памяти.
new Robot - конструкция, которая сообщает, что надо создать новый объект класса Robot.

Robot("Рботот") - вызов конструктора. Т.е. такой функции, которая полностью формирует необходимый вам объект. В нее вы передаете параметр, видимо, имя.

Comment: а понял, тип переменной) а то я не всосал немного!

Answer (score 2):

Переменная enemy не станет "объектом класса Robot" она станет ссылкой на объект(после его создания "new Robot("Рботот");").

Comment: эм... тогда уже я ничего не понял. О_о а в чем принципиальная разница, пока у нас одна такая ссылка?

Comment: @knes, это довольно важная штука в системе хранения переменных. Value-типы хранятся как есть: переменная указывает на место в памяти, где расположены сами данные. Reference-типы, такие, как объект, хранят в переменных ссылки на реальные расположения объектов. Предугадать, сколько памяти нужно будет объекту, довольно сложно, и все равно он будет изменять свое состояние, поэтому он располагается в неупорядоченной куче, где проще с этим разбираться. Если бы эта переменная имела тип int, то она сразу бы указывала на число, а ее копирование создавало бы второе число. С объектами все сложнее ->

Comment: Переменная содержит ссылку на объект, и при копировании скопируется сама ссылка на объект, а, значит, **продолжит указывать на тот же объект**.

Там еще много веселостей с этим связано, boxing-unboxing всякий, но это уже более продвинутые товарищи расскажут.

Comment: @Etki, переменная типа int не указывает на число  
(Вы пишете: "Если бы эта переменная имела тип int, то она сразу бы указывала на число"),

она *сама является* числом. 

--

Т.е. память (для определенности машинное слово), которую компилятор ассоциирует с именем переменной в коде содержит биты, которые интерпретируются как число.

А ссылочная переменная (например, enemy у автора) содержит биты, которые интерпретируются как адрес памяти в которой расположены поля экземпляра объекта (по сути тоже цепочки бит).

--

Это уже всем. Изучите наконец, как реально работает компьютер.

Comment: @avp: Всё же, начинать нужно с C, да.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я только начинал изучать java, то читал книгу, и там была приведена такая аналогия. Объект это клубок ниток, ссылка на объект - нить ведущая к клубку.  
В вашем случае `Robot` это тип клубка (например зеленый), `enemy` - одна нить клубка, а выражение `new Robot("Рботот")` создает сам клубок.   
И, допустим, при таком действии `Robot otherEnemy = enemy`, вы не создаёте еще один объект, а копируете ссылку, т.е. у объекта появляется еще одна нить. Через нити можно работать с объектом.